# can't stop failed threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

i have a problem to stop threads, when something went wrong. If all runs like planed (and the run() goes through), i can stop the threads with my stop_thread() function, but anyway, they nearly never stop automatically and i have no clue why.

```
class sample_thread:

def __init__(self):
    self._running = True

def stop(self):
    self._running = False


def run():
    try:
        do something
    except:
        do something
        self._running = False
    finally:
        do something
        self._running = False
```

so this is my thread class. 
i have the most time 2 threads (excl. main) running and want to stop them after a certain time, if they not finished.

```
def stop_thread(p):
print(time.time()-p['start'])
if time.time() - p['start'] > 240:
    try:
        p['thread_name'].stop()
        do something more
        p['thread_instance'].join(10)
        if p['thread_instance'].is_alive():
            print('[-] Thread should be dead, but is still alive. Try again later')
            p['thread_name'].stop()
            p['thread_instance'].join(10)
            return False
        else:
            print('[+] Failed thread successful stopped')
        return True
    except:
        print('[-] Error occured in stop_thread')
```

'p' is a dict with a few infos about the thread (start-time, name, instance etc).
So my problem is basically, that when something unexpected happend and the code goes into the if-clause, i am not able to stop the thread anymore. No matter how often it returns False and go through the stop_thread function.
Any ideas whats wrong with my code or how i can fix it and reliable kill my threads?
i would be glad for every help!
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot kill a Python thread from another Python thread. In addition, if you attempt to kill another Python thread that's in the same process that you are, you may end up killing yourself. You can only request that the thread stop through some message channel that you've set up.

For example, you might consider passing a `queue` to the thread:

```
class SampleThread():
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q

    def run(self):
        while True:
           do_some_work()
           if not self.q.empty():
               return
```

Comment: ok.. short backgroundstory: i have ~6k files and need to work with them on vms and i thought threading would be a good idea. But if i can't stop them reliable i end up with a few hundreds of running threads... my script should run automatically a few days, till all files are finished. You thing threading is in my case good or bad?

Comment: Are you aware of the GIL? In Python you only get 1 core. If you want more, then use multiprocessing.

Comment: thanks for your answer and help. This is the first time i work with python and also the first time with threading, so i have no clue what is best for my code. Is it easier to reliable stop a process in multiprocessing than a thread in threading? if so, then i will try to implement it.